# AWS CodeBuild Nodejs Runtime

Tags: aws-codebuild

Does AWS CodeBuild already has aws-cli installed? If yes, do i still need to configure a profile or a role attached to codebuild would be sufficient?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, the answer is 'Yes'. The curated images have the aws-cli installed.

For the second question, the service role you provided in the project would be use, but you could still configure your profile if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clearer and concise: CodeBuild can't have aws-cli installed, but the images it uses to run a build can have it.

Images managed by AWS CodeBuild do have AWS CLI and you can verify it by simply adding `aws --version` to one of you commands (pre_build might be a good place for that).

Same check can be done for the custom images, if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details on the Github page on what packages are installed in the images. In the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) you can find the links to the according Github pages.